# How do i deploy a script to heroku that only runs at a scheduled time

Tags: go, heroku, cron, heroku-cli

I have a script written in Golang that does some http requests and store information  in an external database. I want this script to be run once a day at a time that i set. Now i'm dealing with how to deploy it and my first option is Heroku since that's the platform i'm most familiar with. My problem is that i don't want the script to be run when i deploy it for the first time or every time i deploy an update.

Instead i was thinking about using scheduler add-on and set a time for the script to be executed. Is this possible or is there a more effective configuration for the script to be run only at a specified time?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You should use gocron https://github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron

and run permanent your dino on heroku

in gocron you can shedule your services

```
gocron.Every(1).Second().Do(task)
gocron.Every(2).Seconds().Do(task)
gocron.Every(1).Minute().Do(task)
gocron.Every(2).Minutes().Do(task)
gocron.Every(1).Hour().Do(task)
gocron.Every(2).Hours().Do(task)
gocron.Every(1).Day().Do(task)
gocron.Every(2).Days().Do(task)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use heroku [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), you can give it a command to run and choose how often you want to run it and heroku runs it for you.